# A Prepaid Sim card data 3G for the use in Egypt, Israel and Jordan

Tags: cellphones, data-plans, pre-pay

I will be going to Egypt, Israel and Jordan as a tourist in a few month time.

I understand that I can easily buy [a prepaid data plan](http://prepaidisraelisim.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=65) when I am in Israel as a tourist. But can I use this plan in Egypt and Jordan as well? Is there any plans that allow me to browse internet freely on my mobile phones in Egypt, Israel and Jordan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you will have to buy a new one in each of the other countries to avoid extortionate roaming charges. It is really easy in Egypt (I just popped in to a Vodafone store in Cairo airport and had the SIM in 15 minutes). The last time I bought a SIM in Jordan (2005) it was not a big problem either.